# Como criar uma lista no MailChimp, via API?

Tags: envio-de-email, api, newsletter

Quero fazer a comunicação do meu site com a MailChimp de forma automática.

Comment: tente dar mais detalhes

Comment: quero criar uma lista no mailchimp através do meu site. Quando um administrador lançar um evento no site, será criado uma lista no mailchimp para este evento de forma automática. Isto é possível?

Comment: Você chegou a estudar a API? Em qual linguagem de programação está trabalhando?

Comment: Estou estudando a API. O meu código esta em PHP. a API atual é 2.0 e nela não encontrei nenhum método para esta comunicação. Na 1.3 há um método que descritivamente é o que preciso, mas quando faço a comunicação o retorno é de que não há mais o método na API. 
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/partnerapi/1.3/createlist.func.php
Retorno: Method createList is not exported by this server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu recomendo fazer como eu fiz. Eu exportei a minha lista diretamente pelo banco de dados, utilizando a opção do PHPMyAdmin de exportar como .CSV e o MailChimp reconheceu os campos na hora da importação. Muito simples.

Aí então você pode trabalhar com os formulários de captura do MailChimp e administrar essa lista sempre por lá.

Comment: Mas desta forma terei que fazer a importação manualmente. Preciso de uma comunicação automática. Considerando que eu ja tenho o CSV no meu servidor, como faço para o importá-lo no mailchimp?

Comment: Mas você pretende continuar capturando e-mails com o seu próprio sistema? Você não acha mais prático utilizar os formulários do MailChimp? Pois desta forma você só faria essa importação manual uma vez

Comment: Se você realmente necessita utilizar a API, a página com o método de subscrição é essa: [link](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php). Você já testou ou não está conseguindo utilizar a API corretamente?

Comment: Ainda não usei este método, mas pelo que entendi ele adiciona emails a uma lista e estou precisando criar uma list. Estou conseguindo consumir os outros métodos, mas pelo que entendi da API eu preciso de algo assim: [createList](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/partnerapi/1.3/createlist.func.php), e é este método que não consigo consumir e nem encontrar nada parecido na API 2.0.

Comment: Entendi o que você quer. Realmente não encontrei também esse mesmo método na API 2.0. Mas você pode tentar usar [esse](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/segment-add.php). No caso você cria uma lista geral lá no MailChimp e adiciona seguimentos à ela, na prática funciona como várias sublistas.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.